# A quale misura si riferisce il modo di dire "di misura"?

Tags: idioms

Secondo [Hoepli](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/M/misura.shtml) ***vincere di stretta misura*** significa:

> - Vincere per pochissimo, con un minimo vantaggio.

inoltre:

> - Viene dal linguaggio agonistico, dove si riferisce al momento del taglio del traguardo.

Il significato è chiaro, ma a quale misura in particolare si fa riferimento? o è semplicemente un modo di dire del mondo delle corse dove la "misura" è un concetto generico di distanza?

Comment: Accertato che ”di misura“ è equivalente a ”di stretta misura“, direi che si riferisce a qualsiasi unità si adoperi per misurare il distacco.

Comment: @egreg - sì, ma il modo di dire non è "di distanza" o "di distacco" per esempio, per cui mi viene da pensare che la "misura" forse avesse un significato preciso. Mi rendo conto che è una domanda "cavillosa" e impopolare... ma forse qualcuno ha maggiori informazioni a riguardo.

Comment: Il Treccani alla voce [“misura”](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/misura/) riporta al punto 1.d: «fig. *Fare le cose a misura*, con esattezza, con precisione, ma per lo più con riferimento a chi si limita a fare o a dare il minimo indispensabile, senza affatto largheggiare, e perciò con miseria, con taccagneria. *Vincere di misura, di stretta m.*, in competizioni sportive, con piccolissimo vantaggio: *ha ottenuto una vittoria di stretta misura*.» [segue]

Comment: [segue]  Parrebbe quindi che in questa accezione “misura” si riferisca in particolare alla *precisione*: cioè il tal concorrente o squadra ha vinto in maniera molto precisa, spesso nel senso del minimo punteggio possibile per vincere (un singolo gol di differenza, per esempio).

Comment: @DaG - interessante, per cui la "misura" potrebbe riferirsi "all'unita di misura" dello sport in questione, in secondi o in metri/centimetri o punti segnati per esempio.

Answer (score 1):

L'espressione, come già detto, significa vincere di poco ovvero che la vittoria non è stata netta a tal punto che in senso figurato c'è bisogno di misurare il minimo vantaggio del vincitore per rendersi conto che abbia vinto.
Un esempio classico è quello della corsa, quando due corridori arrivano all'unisono e per capire chi ha vinto si ricorre alla "misura" (fotofinish).
Nel calcio, "vittoria di misura" non significa semplicemente vincere con un solo gol di scarto, ma anche che le due squadre si solo equivalse in campo.